# Installing R package - how to change paths listed in installation scripts

Tags: r, path, installation

I'm trying to install an R package that was sent to me as a compressed .zip file which I decompressed; its contents look like this:

```
$ ls -a testingneutrality
.
..
.DS_Store
.Rbuildignore
.Rhistory
.Rproj.user
.git
.gitignore
DESCRIPTION
NAMESPACE
R
data
figure
testingneutrality.Rproj
vignettes
```

Having read [these instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Installing-packages), I tried:

```
R CMD INSTALL -l /path/to/library testingneutrality
```

which produced a warning suggesting my problem has to do with installation scripts:

```
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file '/Users/marcwilliams/Google Drive/early_events/testingneutrality/data/testdata.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
```

I don't know who `Marc Williams` is but that exact path doesn't exist on my machine; what does exist is the relative path: `/testingneutrality/data/testdata.RData`. 
**Seems like the thing to do is change this path in the installation scripts but I have no idea how that works. Any help would be appreciated.**

In case it matters:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```

Comment: Did you get a _package_, or just a bunch of scripts and data zipped up into a zip file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a package because it contains all the same sorts of stuff I see in other packages

Comment: You may be able to just unzip it into your packages directory. The R CMD stuff is when you need to install from source, which is quite different.

Comment: I tried unzipping it into my packages directory and now the package name shows up as an auto-complete suggestion for the library() command but gives an error message saying there is no such package.

Comment: You shouldn't need unzip it before installing it, run: `R CMD INSTALL testingneutrality.zip` (that doesn't mean that something isn't wrong with the source code of the package regarding how the paths were encoded)